# как из combobox получить id delphi

Tags: sql-server, запрос, delphi-7, combobox

В проге при выборе cbb иметься значение, затем при нажатии другую кнопку работает запрос и в запросе получает id combobox. Запрос работает в SQL. Что-то делаю не так в ItemIndex помогите пожалуйста, как мне получить id при выборе cbb.

```
OplataSub.SQL.Clear;
OplataSub.SQL.Add('SELECT b.name_subagent as NameSub, a.data as Date, a.summa_kredit as Oplata ');
OplataSub.SQL.Add('FROM Facial as a, Subagent as b ');
OplataSub.SQL.Add('WHERE b.id=a.subagent_id and ');
OplataSub.SQL.Add('a.subagent_id='+#39+cbb4.Items[cbb4.ItemIndex]+#39+'  and ');
OplataSub.SQL.Add('cast(a.data as date)>='+#39+StringReplace(FormatDateTime('yyyy/MM/dd',frmPriud.dtp1.Date),'.','/',[rfReplaceAll])+#39+' and cast(a.data as date)<='+#39+StringReplace(FormatDateTime('yyyy/MM/dd',frmPriud.dtp2.Date),'.','/',[rfReplaceAll])+#39+' ');
OplataSub.SQL.Add('group by a.data, a.summa_kredit, b.name_subagent ');
Clipboard.AsText:=OplataSub.SQL.Text;
OplataSub.Open;
```

ошибка в проге

[image]

Comment: У вас ошибка конвертации строкового в целое. Рекомендую вывести полученные значения получения id, из комбобокса, замен строк и так далее в вопрос, чтобы было понятно где искать

Comment: Начните с параметризации запроса. OplataSub - это же объект класса TADOQuery? У него есть свойство Params. Вообще a.subagent_id по названию вроде бы как должен быть INT-ом, а вы ему строку подсовываете.